# Pandas: добавляется лишняя ячейка при назначении индексного столбца

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

В датасете уже есть индексная колонка. Фрагмент файла:

```
Index,Height,Weight
1,65.78331,112.9925
2,71.51521,136.4873
3,69.39874,153.0269
4,68.2166,142.3354
5,67.78781,144.2971
```

Ни одного лишнего символа.

Когда я пытаюсь сделать первую колонку индексной

```
data = pandas.read_csv('0030_dataset_weights_heights.csv', index_col="Index")
data
```

То при выводе таблицы почему-то добавляется лишняя ячейка сверху, из-за этого происходит смещение

[image: вывод через Jupyter]

Если не назначать индексную колонку, то pandas ожидаемо назначит ее сам, при этом по строкам все будет отображаться нормально без смещений

```
data = pandas.read_csv('0030_dataset_weights_heights.csv')
data
```

[image: вывод через Jupyter]

Как мне правильно назначить индексную колонку? Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это просто имя индекса - не обращайте на него внимания.

При желании от него можно избавиться:

```
In [13]: df
Out[13]:
         Height    Weight
Index
1      65.78331  112.9925
2      71.51521  136.4873
3      69.39874  153.0269
4      68.21660  142.3354
5      67.78781  144.2971

In [14]: df.index.name
Out[14]: 'Index'

In [15]: df = df.rename_axis(None)

In [16]: df
Out[16]:
     Height    Weight
1  65.78331  112.9925
2  71.51521  136.4873
3  69.39874  153.0269
4  68.21660  142.3354
5  67.78781  144.2971

In [17]: df.index.name
```

---

**UPDATE:**  не делайте так:

```
In [20]: df = df.rename_axis('Index', axis=1)

In [21]: df
Out[21]:
Index    Height    Weight
1      65.78331  112.9925
2      71.51521  136.4873
3      69.39874  153.0269
4      68.21660  142.3354
5      67.78781  144.2971

In [22]: df.columns.name    # <--- NOTE: we've named column's axis as "Index"!
Out[22]: 'Index'
```

Comment: Спасибо. А если я хочу удалить не название, а ту пустую ячейку сверху над названием Index, чтобы названия колонок были в одну строку?

Comment: @Rugert, так не получится - либо вы имеете(показываете) имя индекса и тогда будет пустая строка или нет - тогда и пустой строки не будет. Оба варианта есть в моем ответе...

Comment: @Rugert, можно сделать "dirty hack" и назвать ось столбцов - "Index" - добавил в ответ...